# How does Rails deal with method-name-unfriendly enum values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a (Rails) class that has the following enum value:

```
class DeploymentRequest
  enum frequency: ['One-off', 'Monthly', 'Quarterly', 'Annual']
  #...
end
```

As per the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) (although slightly to my surprise, case-sensitively), a DeploymentRequest has such instance methods as `#Monthly?`, `#Monthly!`, `#Quarterly?` and so on (and the class method `.Monthly`). But the 'One-off' value is throwing it and/or me. I've tried

```
dr.One_off?
dr.Oneoff?
dr.oneoff? # (one lives in hope)
```

But none work (and Pry/IRB aren't suggesting any helpful alternatives). What's happening here? Has Rails just not defined any such set of methods, or has it named them something I haven't found?

Comment: It may be easier to change `One-off` to something like `OneOff` or `Oneoff`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails converts these enums into symbols. You'll be able to see some of these methods by looking at the difference in instance methods between your model and ActiveRecord::Base (assuming that's what you're using):

```
DeploymentRequest.instance_methods - ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods
> [:Quarterly?, :Quarterly!, :Annual?, :Annual!, :"One-off?", :"One-off!", :Monthly?, :Monthly!, ....
```

You can see that the method you need is ":One-off?", which is hard to call. But you can use send:

```
dr.send(:"One-off?")
```

Ugly, but without changing the enum value might be your only option.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty gross misuse of `ActiveRecord::Enum`. Its not intended to store the human friendly strings you want to use on the frontend. Rather its meant to be used to map a set of integers in the database to named states in the model. If the mapping does not follow [the Ruby conventions for method naming](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#naming-conventions) you're doing it wrong.

If you want to display the mappings of an enum on the frontend you should use the I18n module or some other kind of mapping that maps the enum keys to the human readable version:

```
en:
  deployment_request:
    frequencies:
      one_off:  'One-off'
      monthly:  'Monthly'
      quarterly: 'Quarterly' 
      annual: 'Annual'
```

---

```
I18n.t :"deployment_request.frequencies.#{deployment_request.frequency}"
```